# How to import the css in the plugin admin area?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to insert it using the following code. The css file style.css is just inside the plugin's directory.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'callback_for_setting_up_scripts');
function callback_for_setting_up_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'namespace', 'style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'namespace' );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just hook your callback into admin_print_styles, i.e.:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'mytheme_add_init' );
```

Alternately, you could add an is_admin() conditional wrapper inside your callback, and hook into wp_enqueue_scripts:

```
function mytheme_add_init() {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        $file_dir=get_bloginfo('template_directory');
        wp_enqueue_style("functions", $file_dir."/scripts/custom.css", false, "1.0", "all");
        wp_enqueue_script("rm_script", $file_dir."/scripts/custom.js", false, "1.0");
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_add_init' );
```

But the absolute best approach is to hook into your Theme's admin page, via admin_print_styles-appearance_page_{pagename}:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-appearance_page_{pagename}', 'mytheme_add_init', 11 );
```

This is a custom hook specifically for your appearance page, as defined via your add_theme_page() call.